# index does not remain fixed inside a foreach loop in php

Tags: php, foreach

For my homework I had to solve a search problem using the Breadth-First-Search method and I decided to do it in PHP (I don't know if that's a good or bad idea), now the problem is solved and I can print the solution in two ways, but from these two ways, one of them is behaving strangely.

The snippet of code that relates to my problem is this:

```
$jarSet = new JarSet();
$searchTree[] = $jarSet;
foreach ($searchTree as $index => &$jarSet){
//  echo '$index: '.$index.'<br>'; <--- Way#1: Works fine and shows correct indices
  $success = jarFilledOneExistsIn($jarSet); //<--- Check whether any of the jars contains 1 litre of water
  if(!$success){
    generateChildren($jarSet,$searchTree);
  } else {
//  echo '$index: '.$index.'<br>'; <--- Way#2: Shows indices different from the ones in Way#1
    print_solution($index,$jar_set_action_list);
  }
  if($index==10000) break; //<--- Keeps searching until index 10,000
}
```

I expected both `$index`s to print the same numbers, but they are different and I have checked them, it turns out that the numbers printed in first way are the right answers. But why is really Way#2 giving different results?

Comment: Can you provide the data and details for which you have verified this? From this code, that variable is not alerted and should be the same.

Comment: @Qirel Here are codes and results on Pastebin: way#1 https://pastebin.com/4mfULrwm #result_of_way1 https://pastebin.com/KEmvCqfF way#2 https://pastebin.com/DvyHXgqS #result_of_way2 https://pastebin.com/WFRq3tPe If you go to the bottom most result, for way#1 it is index: 9227 but for way#2 it is index: 9203. (First one is the right one.) (sorry for long pastebins)

Comment: @Qirel Sorry for bothering, but do you have any idea why this is behaving like this? or you didn't conclude anything?